# IBM Domino Java correct method of recycling objects

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

```
 public lotus.domino.Document getParentItemFromServiceOrder() throws NotesException{
    findRegels();
     lotus.domino.Document orderRegelTemp = OrderRegels.getFirstDocument();
     lotus.domino.Document temp1 = null;  
     while(orderRegelTemp != null)
     {

        if(orderRegelTemp.getItemValueString("PARENTLINEITEM").equals("1"))
        {
             if(temp1 != null) temp1.recycle();
             if(OrderRegels != null)OrderRegels.recycle();
             return orderRegelTemp;

        }
        else{
            temp1 = OrderRegels.getNextDocument(orderRegelTemp);  
            orderRegelTemp.recycle();  // recycle the one we're done with 
            orderRegelTemp = temp1; 
        }
     }//end while
     if(orderRegelTemp != null) orderRegelTemp.recycle();  
     if(temp1 != null) temp1.recycle();
     if(OrderRegels != null)OrderRegels.recycle();
     return null;
 }
```

I wondered if the recycling in the above method is needed or will the objects be automatically recycled when the function has been executed.. Next to this, when do I need to recycle orderRegelTemp if it returned the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Apparently OrderRegels is outside the scope of this method, and I guess you're doing something in findRegels() to initialize it. I might not have done it quite that way, but it's okay. However, you *cannot* recycle OrderRegels inside this method because you are returning orderRegelTemp, which is a child object contained by OrderRegels. When you recycle OrderRegles, all of its children will be recycled. The object that you are returning is therefore going to have been recycled by the time the caller of your method tries to access it. That's going to be a Very Bad Thing.

And that's only the first problem!

After your call to getNextDocument, you assign temp1 to orderRegelTemp, then you loop around and if your if condition hits, the first thing you do is recycle temp1. Since temp1 and orderRegelTemp refer to the same Document object, you just recycled the storage for orderRegelTemp that your method is trying to return! So even if you removed the call to OrderRegels.recycle(), it's still not going to work.

The one thing you are doing correctly is the call to orderRegelTemp.recycle() in your else clause. That is the right thing to do. If you omitted that, then you would be building up lots of C API memory that the Notes API is allocating for those documents, and you could easily run out of memory. This is still true even on 64 bit systems with lots of memory, because of the way the Notes API manages shared memory segments.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning recycling Domino does three things automatically (AFAIK):

- When an agent ends it recycles the Session
- When an object is recycled it recycles all children (-> when an agent ends all its objects get recycled - in general)
- When a thread ends it recycles all databases that were opened by this thread if they weren't touched by any other thread (using the same session)

Domino's automatic recycling does not help you much (in fact it often makes things worse).
But you may automate recycling by using the recycler: http://recycler.sourceforge.io